# How to merge new observable data with previous data with each page increment

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, state-management

With this code when I am scrolling the api call again and it fetch both the previous data and new data and merge together.but i only want to add the new observable data to the existing observable---with each scroll new observable data to be added when page increment.

```cpp
 onSearchOrder() {
  this.orders$ = this.getOrderData(this.page, this.limitOrder).pipe(
    map(res => res),
    catchError(error => throwError(error))
  )
 }    

 getOrderData(page, limitOrder): Observable<any> {
   this.orderApiData(page, limitOrder)
 }    

 orderApiData(params, page, limit) {
   let orderurl = `${xx}/xx/xx?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`;
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   return this.http.post(orderurl, params, options)
     .pipe(map(res => JSON.parse(res['_body']),
       catchError(err => {
         this.errorMessage = err.message;
         return EMPTY
       }))
     )
 } 

 doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
   this.page = this.page + 1;
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.orders$ = combineLatest(this.orders$, this.getOrderData(this.page, this.limitOrder)).pipe(
       map(([firstResult, secondResult]) => {
         return [].concat(firstResult).concat(secondResult)
       })
     );
     console.log('Async operation has ended');
     infiniteScroll.complete();
   }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a Subject that will be the source of all scrolling data
2. After that you can create a Observable piped using [scan](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/scan.html) that will handle the accumulating logic -- every time you emit a new value for the Subject, this observable will join the previous data with the new emitted value.
3. Subscribe to the observable in order to get all the data.

Here's an example:

```js
// 1.
ordersSubject$ = new Subject();

// 2.
orders$ = this.ordersSubject$.pipe(
    scan((a, b) => [...a, ...b], [])
)
```

Then every time you have new data just emit it through the subject

```js
this.getOrderData(this.page, this.limitOrder).subscribe(data => {
    this.ordersSubject$.next(data);
});
```

And to consume the data subscribe in the Observable:

```
orders$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: can i do that without subscribing the data

Comment: you need to subscribe to get the data... is this a request or a store like ngrx? if this is a ngrx you can use the operator `take(1)` to get the data and close the subscription afterwards. If it's a normal request it's not necessary, after complete the subscribe will be closed.